# Remap category type from one data frame to another in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data set: train and test. I want to remap the `category` dtype from the train set to test set so that the categories which are not in the train data set will be eliminated. Right now it works this way but I am thinking whether there is a better and more efficient (or pythonic ways) to achieve this goal.

```py
import pandas as pd
from pandas.api.types import CategoricalDtype

# define data frame. 
df = pd.DataFrame({'One': list('ABCC'), 'Two': list('bccd')})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'One': list('ABCDE'), 'Two': list('debca')})

# Convert one data frame to category type.
df= df.astype('category')

# build dict for category type.
cat_dict = {}
for col in df.columns:
    cat_dict[col]= df[col].cat.categories

# map on the another data frame. 
for key,val in cat_dict.items():
    df2[key] = df2[key].astype(CategoricalDtype(categories=val))
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is also looking for an answer, here is how I end up doing it.

```py
from collections import defaultdict
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator,TransformerMixin
from pandas.api.types import CategoricalDtype

class PandasLabelEncoder(BaseEstimator,TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self):
        self.label_dict = defaultdict(list)

    def fit(self, X):
        X = X.astype('category')
        cols = X.columns
        values = list(map(lambda col: X[col].cat.categories, cols))
        self.label_dict = dict(zip(cols,values))
        # return as category for xgboost or lightgbm 
        return self

    def transform(self,X):
        # check missing columns
        missing_col=set(X.columns)-set(self.label_dict.keys())
        if missing_col:
            raise ValueError('the column named {} is not in the label dictionary. Check your fitting data.'.format(missing_col)) 
        return X.apply(lambda x: x.astype('category').cat.set_categories(self.label_dict[x.name]).cat.codes).astype('category')

    def inverse_transform(self,X):
        return X.apply(lambda x: pd.Categorical.from_codes(codes=x.values,
                                                           categories=self.label_dict[x.name]))

dff1 = pd.DataFrame({'One': list('ABCC'), 'Two': list('bccd')})
dff2 = pd.DataFrame({'One': list('ABCDE'), 'Two': list('debca')})


enc=PandasLabelEncoder()
enc.fit_transform(dff1)
```

```
One Two
0   0   0
1   1   1
2   2   1
3   2   2
```

```py
dff3=enc.transform(dff2)
dff3
```

```
    One Two
0   0   2
1   1   -1
2   2   0
3   -1  1
4   -1  -1
```

```py
enc.inverse_transform(dff3)
```

```
One Two
0   A   d
1   B   NaN
2   C   b
3   NaN c
4   NaN NaN
```